# Upper bound of $\int^{\pi}_{0} \frac{\operatorname dx}{(\sqrt{2-2\cos(x)})^\alpha}$ for $\alpha\in(0,1)$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

I have the following integral:

$$\int^{\pi}_{0} \frac{\operatorname dx}{(\sqrt{2-2\cos(x)})^\alpha} \qquad \text{for $\alpha\in(0,1)$}$$

Now, I know that I can use the fact that $1-\cos(x)\ge\frac{x^2}{9}$ to apply the Comparison Theorem and show that the integral converges. But I'm asked to find a numeric upper bound for this integral. How should I approach that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the integrand using a half-angle formula:

$$\frac 1{(\sqrt{2(1-\cos x)})^{\alpha}} = \frac 1{(\sqrt{4\sin^2\frac x2})^{\alpha}} \stackrel{0<x\leq \pi}{=}\frac 1{2\sin^{\alpha} \frac x2}$$

So, your integral becomes
$$\frac 12\int_0^{\pi}\frac{dx}{\sin^{\alpha} \frac x2}\stackrel{u=\frac x2}{=}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{du}{\sin^{\alpha} u}$$

To find an upper bound you can use the concavity of $\sin u $ on $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ where you have $\sin u \geq \frac 2{\pi} u$. Hence,

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{du}{\sin^{\alpha} u} \leq \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{\alpha}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{du}{u^{\alpha}}$$

I leave it up to you to evaluate the last integral.